Auto Scroll RecyclerView
I use recycler view show list text. I use function scrollBy to scroll  recycler view automatically.
rcv.scrollBy(2, 0)

But I want to disable scroll by user, only auto scroll. I try disable scroll horizontal by extend LinearLayout Manager
class NonScrollableLinearLayoutManager(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false // Vô hiệu hóa cuộn dọc
    }

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
        return false // Vô hiệu hóa cuộn ngang (nếu cần)
    }
}

But it disable both auto scroll and user scroll
Help me, please

if you want to use the autoscroll only
rcv.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
rcv.scrollBy(2, 0, smoothScroll = true)

and remove the below piece of code
class NonScrollableLinearLayoutManager(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false // Vô hiệu hóa cuộn dọc
    }

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
        return false // Vô hiệu hóa cuộn ngang (nếu cần)
    }
}


I have tried but it is still scrolled
